# How to launch a python file from html

Tags: roslaunch, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy Guys,

I just have a little question. I'll appreciate your support.

I have worked with rosbridge and I don`t have any problem, But I want to launch a python file from html file. Something like that:

....
rosrun filename.py.

Thanks. I'll appreciate your support.

John

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271823/how-to-launch-a-python-file-from-html/) by [JohnPa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32088/johnpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this is not possible, but I have not used rosbridge much.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
No, this is not possible. @JohnPa: `rosbridge` is really just that, a bridge. It allows you to connect to a ROS node graph using a JSON based API. Anything you can do with a regular ROS node can be done from javascript. If you want a "python file" to be started based on some event, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-29**:
.. you'll have to create a ROS node that either listens on a topic and publish a message to that topic from javascript, or make the node expose a service and have your html page (again, with javascript) invoke that service. That ROS node can then do anything, including starting your Python file.

**Comment by [JohnPa](https://answers.ros.org/users/32088/johnpa/) on 2017-09-30**:
Thanks! So much. @gvdhoom

Due to your answer I have understood better. But Right now I have this problem.